# OrientDB Cluster Configuration Using VM

Tags: virtual-machine, cluster-computing, hazelcast, multicast, orientdb2.2

I am trying to form a orientDB cluster using orientdb-enterprise-2.2.3 using the VM hosted on local server. The VM have the configuration of Fedora OS 18. I have attached the orientdb-server-config.xml and hazelcast.xml file.

**orientdb-server-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<orient-server>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.handler.OGraphServerHandler">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="50" name="graph.pool.max"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="${distributed}" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/default-distributed-db-config.json" name="configuration.db.default"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/hazelcast.xml" name="configuration.hazelcast"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OJMXPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="true" name="profilerManaged"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/automatic-backup.json" name="config"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OServerSideScriptInterpreter">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="SQL" name="allowedLanguages"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
    </handlers>
    <network>
        <sockets>
            <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerTLSSocketFactory" name="ssl">
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
                </parameters>
            </socket>
            <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerTLSSocketFactory" name="https">
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
                </parameters>
            </socket>
        </sockets>
        <protocols>
            <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
            <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpDb" name="http"/>
        </protocols>
        <listeners>
            <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
            <listener protocol="http" socket="default" port-range="2480-2490" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
                <commands>
                    <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetStaticContent" pattern="GET|www GET|studio/ GET| GET|*.htm GET|*.html GET|*.xml GET|*.jpeg GET|*.jpg GET|*.png GET|*.gif GET|*.js GET|*.css GET|*.swf GET|*.ico GET|*.txt GET|*.otf GET|*.pjs GET|*.svg GET|*.json GET|*.woff GET|*.woff2 GET|*.ttf GET|*.svgz" stateful="false">
                        <parameters>
                            <entry value="Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache" name="http.cache:*.htm *.html"/>
                            <entry value="Cache-Control: max-age=120" name="http.cache:default"/>
                        </parameters>
                    </command>
                    <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.server.command.OServerCommandGetGephi" pattern="GET|gephi/*" stateful="false"/>
                </commands>
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="utf-8" name="network.http.charset"/>
                    <parameter value="true" name="network.http.jsonResponseError"/>
                </parameters>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
    </network>
    <storages/>
    <users>
        <user resources="*" password="root" name="root"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
    </users>
    <properties>
        <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
        <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
        <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
    </properties>
    <isAfterFirstTime>true</isAfterFirstTime>
</orient-server>
```

**hazelcast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>orientdb</name>
        <password>orientdb</password>
    </group>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true">2434</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>235.1.1.1</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>2434</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
        </join>
    </network>
    <executor-service>
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
    </executor-service>
</hazelcast>
```

But the two nodes are not getting connected in the cluster. I am trying the multicast join for clustering. The individual servers are working fine.
What might be the issue with the multicast clustering?

Comment: any reasons to use multicast in hazelcast config? Have you tried to specify IP addresses?

Comment: @VikGamov I have tried with Tcp-Ip join and the clustering works fine but i need to explore the multicast as well. Multicast works on physical machcines but not on VM hosted in the local network.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Deep Mistry try iptables firewall configuration as the ports might be blocked by firewall

Comment: I have tried the firewall configuration and verified using curl both the VM's are accessible and transferring an http response. But still the issue persists